# App Engine - Cloud Sql - java.sql.SQLException: This Connection is closed

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

After a while I got this error, so how do I make sure that the connection is not dead before giving my singleton?

Here is my code:

```
public static Connection getInstance() throws Exception {

    if(connection != null) {
        return connection;
    }

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://"+instanceName+"/vidaao");

    return connection;

}
```

Stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: This Connection is closed.     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.Exceptions.newConnectionClosedException(Exceptions.java:52)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection.throwIfNotOpen(Connection.java:633)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection.getHoldability(Connection.java:194)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection.createStatement(Connection.java:123)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection.createStatement(Connection.java:54)
>     at db.DbUser.exist(DbUser.java:209)     at
>   controller.CtrlUser.login(CtrlUser.java:343)  at
>   vidaao.ConnectServlet.doPost(ConnectServlet.java:36)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:380)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

I tried to use isClosed() but doesn't work and isValid() looks like it is working but it's slowing down the connection to the database each time

Comment: Without stack trace hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: Here i attached my stack trace @Nambari

Answer (score 2):

Calling [Connection#isValid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29) would be the best approach, but yes, it pings the database to ensure the connection is valid.

I noticed you are not using the standard mysql connector/j driver inside of AppEngine, I'd recommend giving that a try. It will not time out the connections on the server the same way that the older driver does.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database for the classname of the JDBC driver class to use within AppEngine as well as the URL to use.

Hope this helps,
Rob

Comment: thank you, i just implemented this, I will give a shot in production for a few days, to see if it will solve the problem!